# BASH, if statement not operating as expected

Tags: linux, bash, process, ps

As the title says, Im trying to echo only the process that older than 2600000 seconds, but it echos processes with etimes less than 2600000.

```
 while read pro; do
 set -- $pro

if [ $2 > 2600000 ]
 then
 echo $2 is bigger than 2600000
 echo "
PID :$1, Process owner :$3, procces begin time: $2 (Seconds ago)  
"
 fi
PIDS_OVER_A_MONTH+=("PID:$2, Process owner:$2")



done < <(ps -eo pid,etimes,user )
```

This is my output, as you can see, it echos etimes that are less than 2600000 (don't notice PIDS_OVER... list):

```
PID :25271, Process owner :yonatanh, procces begin time: 2082286 (Seconds ago)  

2082286 is bigger than 2600000

PID :25275, Process owner :yonatanh, procces begin time: 2082286 (Seconds ago)  

2082284 is bigger than 2600000

PID :25299, Process owner :yonatanh, procces begin time: 2082284 (Seconds ago)  

7224 is bigger than 2600000

PID :29549, Process owner :it, procces begin time: 7224 (Seconds ago)  

6843 is bigger than 2600000

PID :30225, Process owner :yonatanh, procces begin time: 6843 (Seconds ago)  

2079327 is bigger than 2600000

PID :31324, Process owner :yonatanh, procces begin time: 2079327 (Seconds ago)
```

Comment: try `$2 -gt 2600000` for numeric comparisons

Comment: @markp-fuso i get error line 19: [: ELAPSED: integer expression expected

Comment: Also, notice the empty file `2600000` in your current directory? If you *do* want to perform string comparisons with `>`, you have to escape it to prevent it from being treated as a redirection operator. `[ $2 > 2600000 ]` is equivalent to `[ $2 ] > 2600000`.

Comment: This is an extremely common error.  I strongly believe one easy solution to the error is to *never* use `[`.   The error seems more obvious when you write it as `if test $2 > 2600000`, since the reader is not confused by the incorrect belief that `[` and `]` are part of the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did say `bash`, right? Do you need portability to other parsers?

I'd use `bash`.

```
while read -r pid etimes user; do
  if (( etimes > 2600000 )); then
     echo "$etimes is bigger than 2600000"
     printf "\nPID :%s, Process owner :%s, proccess begin time: %s (Seconds ago)  \n\n" "$pid" "$user" "$etimes"
     PIDS_OVER_A_MONTH+=("PID:$pid, Process owner:$user")
  fi
done < <(ps -eo pid,etimes,user )
```

Numeric context `(( ))` makes it pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

A couple recommended changes:

- use `-gt` for numeric comparisons
- add `--no-headers` to suppress the `ps` header line
- read `ps` values directly into variables

Pulling this all together:

```
while read -r pid elapsed owner
do
    if [ "${elapsed}" -gt 2600000 ]
    then
        echo "${elapsed} is bigger than 2600000"
        printf "\nPID : ${pid}, Process owner : ${owner}, procces begin time : ${elapsed} (Seconds ago)\n\n"
    fi
    PIDS_OVER_A_MONTH+=("PID:${pid}, Process owner:${owner}")
done < <(ps --no-headers -eo pid,etimes,user )
```